# Create HTML table from multiple lines of strings

Tags: php, html-table

I want to take a text file formatted like so:

*note I can change the format of the stored messages, basically there are delimiters and different lines

```
;68.229.164.10:4/5/2013:Hello 
;71.73.174.13:4/6/2013:Oh Hey
```

(;IPADDRESS:TIMESTAMP:MESSAGE)

and put it in a table that looks like so:

```
 IP                       Time                  Message
 68.229.164.10            4/6/2013              Hello
 71.73.174.13             4/6/2013              Oh Hey
```

Comment: I tried to put the values on their own lines and add them to a 3 column table, cell by cell, generating new rows as needed, but it only made new rows and couldn't add to columns. I'm used to programming in VB and I am making this as an extension to a VB program to publish updates to the web for simple things.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use something like the following:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

And then format the output accordingly.

From Example 1 on the above referenced page:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

so, you could do something like this...

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("path_to_your_data_file", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><td></td>IP<td>Time</td><td>Message</td></tr>';

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ":")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        if ($num > 2) {
           echo '<tr>';
           for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
              echo '<td>'.$data[$c].'</td>';
           }
           echo '</tr>';
        }
    }

    echo '</table>';
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: http://tros.jgetrost.com/writekeys.php     <the page where the messages are written

Comment: Can you clarify what your two comments mean?

Comment: the one page has a box where you can enter the message, the other page displays the ip, timedate, message in a table

Comment: its basically just a simple way to write and read a text file, I just want the text file formatted into a table on the viewing page.

Comment: maybe this will sound more simpler, I want each line to be a row, and each row to have 3 columns, one for ip, another for timestamp, and finally one for the message.

Comment: Did my answer not work for you? Granted you'd have to change the default delimiter from a comma to a ":", but that should do what you need. If you know you only want the first three fields, you can even lose the for loop and simply reference `$data[0], $data[1], and $data[2]` in your while loop as you go through each line.

Comment: yes, Ive got it figured out now it looks like, but I'm getting a random extra column on http://tros.jgetrost.com/readkeys.php

Comment: Doesn't look like an extra column. Looks like your first row is empty (or only has one column). You could add a conditional to your output which only spits out rows if the col count is greater than 2 (or something like that).

Comment: I edited the bottom example to include a check for number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a=";68.229.164.10:4/5/2013:Hello
;71.73.174.13:4/6/2013:Oh Hey";

preg_match_all('{;(.*?):(.*?):(.*)}',$a,$d);

//set th
$d[0][0]='IP';
$d[0][1]='TIME';
$d[0][2]='Message';

$table = '<table>'.PHP_EOL;
foreach($d AS $tr){
    $row = PHP_EOL;
    foreach($tr AS $td){
        $row .= "<td>{$td}</td>".PHP_EOL;
    }
     $table .= "<tr>{$row}</tr>".PHP_EOL;
}
$table .= "</table>".PHP_EOL;
echo $table;
```